# Class \GuzzleHttp\Client not found composer

Tags: php, composer-php, guzzle6

I  have been installing Guzzle using composer and try to use it,
but I get an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Conf\GuzzleHttp\Client' not found in /var/www/html/4travelo_beta/config/RequestConf.php:28 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/4travelo_beta/config/RequestConf.php(85): Conf\RequestConf->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/4travelo_beta/config/RequestConf.php on line 28

this is my directory structure :

[image: Dirctory Structure]

and this is my code:

```
 namespace Conf ;

    require '../vendor/autoload.php';

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri;

    class RequestConf
    {
     /**
        /**
         * @var Client HTTPClient object
         */
        private $httpClient;

        /**
         * HotelApiClient Constructor they initialize SDK Client.
         * @param int $timeout HTTP Client timeout
         */

        function __construct()
        {
            $this->$httpClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_url' => 'https://api.test.com/']);
        }
}
```

my composer.json :

```
    {
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {

            "Conf\\": "config/",
            "Model\\": "model/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
    }
}
```

i have been updating my composer but Guzzle class still not work, can someone tell me why ?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Simply try `= new Client(...)`, because you've already imported `GuzzleHttp\Client`, or just remove this import.

You are trying to create an instance of `GuzzleHttp\Client`, and because there are no imported namespaces like `GuzzleHttp` (with `use`), PHP tries to find the class in the current namespace. In the end you get the error about `Config\GuzzleHttp\Client`.

So it should be like:

```
 function __construct()
 {
      $this->httpClient = new Client(['base_url' => 'https://api.test.com/']); // Please also note removed '$' from httpClient, because it a field.
 }
```

Comment: Like `new GuzzleHttp\Client\GuzzleHttp\Client` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `composer dumpautoload` so it will update your autoload include file.